# Microsoft Sharepoint API - Access to shared folder by shared URL

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to access Microsoft SharePoint shared folder by API call?? I have share link in format `https://<company>-my.sharepoint.com/<path-to-folder>` and I need to access it with some API call. I got it working with One Drive, unfortunately haven't been so lucky with Sharepoint.

Comment: Did you want to get a share link of a shared folder on the sharepoint using the MS Graph API?

Comment: I don't understand. I have this URL of the shared folder and I want to access its content using API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description and the comment, the MS Graph API may not be supported to access the shared folder content using the URL.

We can using the sharepoint rest API. For more information, we can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)